# Problemas com método count em uma queryset do django

Tags: python, django, aplicação-web, método, viewmodel

Eu estou com uma situação estranha com o django e o método count, eu tenho uma queryset que eu chamei de intervalos e então tenho uma variável `qtd_intervalo` onde eu armazeno o `intervalos.count()` aí faço os testes:

```
if qtd_intervalo > 1:
if qtd_intervalo ==1:

        qtd_intervalos = intervalos.count()
        if qtd_intervalos > 1:
            #se existem intervalos em aberto então eu irei finalizalos e pronto
            intervalos.update(finalizada = True,data_finalizacao = agora,data_final=agora,usuario_edicao = usuario)
            _horario_final = "{0}:{1}".format(agora.hour,agora.minute)
            usuario.flags['em_trabalho'] = True
            usuario.flags['em_intervalo'] = False
            usuario.save()
            _html = _FECHAR_PONTO + _ABRIR_INTERVALO
            return {"sucesso":True,'html':_html,
                    "mensagem":"Foram finalizados {0} intervalos às {1}".format(qtd_intervalos,_horario_final)}
        elif qtd_intervalos == 1:
            _hora_inicio = intervalos[0].data_inicial
            _horario_inicio = "{0}:{1}".format(_hora_inicio.hour,_hora_inicio.minute)
            _horario_final = "{0}:{1}".format(agora.hour,agora.minute)
            intervalos.update(finalizada = True,data_finalizacao = agora,data_final=agora,usuario_edicao = usuario)
            usuario.flags['em_trabalho'] = True
            usuario.flags['em_intervalo'] = False
            usuario.save()
            _html = _FECHAR_PONTO + _ABRIR_INTERVALO
            return {"sucesso":True,'html':_html,
                    "mensagem":"Foi finalizado o intervalo aberto em {0} às {1}".format(_horario_inicio,_horario_final)}
        else:
            intervalo = Calendario(dependencia = calendario_ponto,usuario = usuario)
            _data_final = agora + relativedelta(minutes=30)
            nome = "Intervalo de {0}".format(usuario)
            descricao = "Intervalo: {0}".format(agora)
            flags = {'cancelada':False,'lida':False,
                'situacao_finalizacao':{"status":"aguardando início",'cor':'gray','icone':"fa fa-hourglass-o fa-2x",
                                        'icone_normal':"fa fa-hourglass-o",'estilo':'default',},
                'percentual':0,"ponto":True,"intervalo":True,"em_servico":False}
```

etc.

Mas vez ou outra dentro deste if eu recebo o erro:

> File "/home/caaorg/caaorg/institucional/models.py" in
> abrir_fechar_intervalo
> 4374.                 _hora_inicio = intervalos[0].data_inicial
>
> File
> "/home/caaorg/virtual-caaorg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
> in **getitem**
> 309.         return qs._result_cache[0]
>
> Exception Type: IndexError at
> /contabilidade/alterar-estado-meu-intervalo/ Exception Value: list
> index out of range

Que não faz sentido porque eu verifiquei antes se a quantidade de itens na queryset é maior que zero...

Django 2.2.16 e python 3.7

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser isso?

Comment: Não vi no seu código onde está inicializado `intervalos`, você poderia atualizar seu post?